# Remote containers on Windows - how?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have been playing around with the Remote containers feature of VS Code. If I have a .devcontainer directory inside my repo, VS code suggests to open the repo using a bind mount.

However, bind mounting to Windows seems to have two major drawbacks:

- File permissions are all wrong. I am not sure what happens if I git commit such a file, maybe I will inadvertedly make non-executable files executable? I think this is a limitation in Docker for windows, but a problem nonetheless.
- CRLF conversion is by default introducing whitespace diffs in all files (This is solved by .gitattributes though).
- I saw that there is an option to clone the repo directly from Github to a named volume, but that does not respect the mount point set in the devcontainer.json file.

So I think my questions is really about: is remote containers at all usable on Windows for practical purposes and if so, how do I best set it up?

Answer (score 1):

While it does work good for me in Windows 10 (2004 update), I recommend using devcontainer using WSL2 as it works "smoother".

The file permissions issue might be fixable using the `remoteUser` property in the `devcontainer.json` file. Just remove the comment and use the `remoteUser` value that is supplied by the template.

Comment: Yes, WSL2 makes things slightly better even though the original problems are still there. (Using macOs or Ubuntu for my dev machine makes things better still, but unfortunately I need Visual Studio 2019 for some use cases, so anything that improves the Windows dev experience improves my productivity).